# Create word dictionary for sentences in a list

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nltk, countvectorizer

I have a list of sentences

`a = [['i am a testing'],['we are working on project']]`

I am trying to create a word dictionary for all the sentences on the list. I tried

```py
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit_transform(a)
coffee_dict2 = vectorizer.vocabulary_
```

And i am getting an error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'`

The result i am expecting is a dictionary

`{'i': 1, 'am': 1, 'testing': 2}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need flatten nested lists:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
coffee_reviews_test = [['i am a testing'],['we are working on project']]

from  itertools import chain

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit_transform(chain.from_iterable(coffee_reviews_test))
```

Another solution:

```
vectorizer.fit_transform([x for y in coffee_reviews_test for x in y])
```

---

```
coffee_dict2 = vectorizer.vocabulary_
print (coffee_dict2)
{'am': 0, 'testing': 4, 'we': 5, 'are': 1, 'working': 6, 'on': 2, 'project': 3}
```